# Rails Regex Match Group Overwriting itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rubular

I am trying to match this string:

NFPA 101 19.7.2.2

and am using this regex:

```
(NFPA) (\w+)(?: ?(?:([^.]+)\.?)+)?
```

This seems to match the string, but the captured groups are not what I'm looking for. I expect:

1. NFPA
2. 101
3. 19
4. 7
5. 2
6. 2

What I get is this:

1. NFPA
2. 101
3. 2

See this rubular example:
http://rubular.com/r/43VY0yyNa7

It's as if that last recurring capture group is being overwritten by the final match. Is there a way to have all of these come back as capture groups as I need?

Added another regex that gives me the similar problem described above:
(NFPA) (.+) (.+?.)+(.+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're using [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) symbol `:` which isn't gonna work to select the string as separate capture group. To overcome the issue you need to use [Positive / Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So, the following *regex* should work in this case :

```
(\w+|\d+[-]\d+)(?=\s?)(?![-])
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vLRSLQ/6)

Comment: That works for that string, but I have multiple other reasons for doing it the way I am. My main issue is that matching group seemingly overwritting itself. Your solution, for instance, would fail on this string: NFPA 101 7-9.3 Where 7-9 should be matched.

Comment: @steventnorris well in that case, you should've mentioned all possible combinations of the string on your question

Comment: I get that. My question was primarily why that matching group in my current regex isn't giving me the expected array, not how to match that string specifically.

Comment: Positive/negative lookahead was the missing piece. Thanks!